# Area51 - how can one user propose more than 5 questions for a given proposal?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51

Specifically in reference to this [user](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/118/geoffrey-chetwood), how did he create 15 proposed questions in one topic? The limit *appears* to be no more than five per user (or, at least has been for myself).

Comment: Incidentally, how come "that user" was able to post any questions at all? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

During the first week of Area 51's private beta there was no question limit, then IIRC it was introduced to 15 before it was set to 5. Since that was during the private beta phase I can't quote meta...

Comment: This is correct

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that limit was there at the beginning.